# How to call onmessage received when app is closed in flutter using fcm?

Tags: dart, flutter

Firebase notifications are not getting called when app is in closed mode..i am using local notifications to display bigpicturestyle notification.But fcm is unable to run onmessage received when app is closed. Any other ways to call onmessage function even when app is closed

Comment: When the app is closed the messages should be shown automatically. When the app is in foreground, the app receives the message and needs to show them itself if you want them shown. Perhaps the structure of the message is incomplete to match the requirements when the app is closed. Can you please add a message example how you send it?

Comment: messages are displaying but not with image.. because we are using local notifications to display image type notification

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795553/217408 might help

Comment: i am sending data message only but still it is not displaying. In flutter how to add

Comment: Hey did you solved the issue.?

Answer (score -1):

Firebase Cloud Messaging can only receive notifications on `onMessage` when the app is in the [foreground](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications#foreground-notifications).

When the app is in the [background](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications#handling-interaction), the notification should be displayed automatically on the device. This behavior can then be handled with `onMessageOpenedApp`.